# Conditional validation issue?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I am trying to set up conditional validation for a RadioButtonList control in a FormView.  Hopefully someone can spot my error.  The validator is only disabled if ThirdPartyInfoTextBox has a text value regardless of rbMTA checked state. I am looking for the validator to be disabled if rbMTA(0) is checked and enabled if rbMTA(1) is checked.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleValidator() {
        var rb = document.getElementById("<%=fvMTAReq.FindControl("rbMTA").ClientID%>");
        var valName = document.getElementById("<%=fvMTAReq.FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator9").ClientID%>");
        if (rb.getElementsByID("rbMTA").checked) {
            ValidatorEnable(valName, false);
        }
        else {
            ValidatorEnable(valName, true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:FormView ID="fvMTAReq" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RID" DataSourceID="sqldsMTA" DefaultMode="Insert" HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbMTA" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ThirdParty") %>' onclick="ToggleValidator()">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="false" Value="true">Yes, I confirm that this material is not subject to an agreement nor was it provided to my lab and/or the Danforth Center by another party.</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="false">No. Explanation:</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ThirdPartyInfoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ThirdPartyInfo") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="40"/>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Validation1" ErrorMessage="" Text="*Required*"
            ControlToValidate="ThirdPartyInfoTextBox" ValidateEmptyText="true" CssClass="RequiredField">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="Validation1" CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit" />
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have made a many syntax errors. Use the below.

```
function ToggleValidator() {
        var rb = document.getElementById('<%=fvMTAReq.FindControl("rbMTA").ClientID%>');
        var valName = document.getElementById('<%=fvMTAReq.FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator9").ClientID%>');
        if (document.getElementByID("rbMTA").checked) {
            ValidatorEnable(valName, false);
        }
        else {
            ValidatorEnable(valName, true);
        }
    }
```

you forgot to escape quotes and in the if condition, you made a typo.

Also add `ClientIDMode` to `Static` to the controls.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I used your code and am getting same result.

Comment: Ok, that works, but the form submit event is firing a server side validation for ThirdPartyInfoTextBox and that is not the desired behavior. Any more ideas?